# Cypher: find actors having more than one role in a movie

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using Movie data set, how can you find the actors acting as more than one role in a movie.

Comment: yes... can you tell a bit more about the data model ? where is the role saved ?

Comment: you can have the movie data set by running :play movies in neo4j browser. It is a sample data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the movies db, `roles` is a list property on :ACTED_IN relationships, so all we need to do is find that particular pattern where the `roles` list is greater than 1:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]-(m:Movie)
WITH a, r.roles as roles, m
WHERE size(roles) > 1
RETURN a, roles, m
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, you can do this more ways... since roles are saved as relationships you can just check, who has more than one relationship to a movie.

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[r]-(m:Movie)
WITH a,m,collect(type(r)) as rels where length(rels) > 1
RETURN a,rels,m
```